# Feign client retryer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I'm just trying to make a retryInterval and retryMaxAttempt read from application.proprties like @Value() not static value , How can i make it ?

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FeignConnectionRetryer implements Retryer {

    private int retryMaxAttempt;
    private long retryInterval;
    private int attempt = 1;


    public FeignConnectionRetryer(int retryMaxAttempt, Long retryInterval) {
        this.retryMaxAttempt = retryMaxAttempt;
        this.retryInterval = retryInterval;
    }

    @Override
    public void continueOrPropagate(RetryableException e) {
        log.info("Feign retry attempt {} due to {} ", attempt, e.getMessage());

        if (attempt++ == retryMaxAttempt)
            throw e;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(retryInterval);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Retryer clone() {
        return new FeignConnectionRetryer(3, 2000L);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly make your constructor look like this and put `feign.retry.attempts` `feign.retry.interval` properties in your applicatoin.properties file

```
public FeignConnectionRetryer(
    @Value("${feign.retry.attempts:3}") Integer maxAttempts,
    @Value("${feign.retry.interval:2000}") Long interval
)
```